# Global variables in JavaScript strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables, use-strict

A simple Javascript question, For instance I have an Angular app.js like this;

```
'use strict';

 var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp',[]);
```

I read that using "use strict" in beginning of a Javascript file makes all vars in that file to be treated in strict mode, which means will it throw an error when you use a global variable(?), but then how can we access that "eventApp" object from all our controllers and services if that's not in global scope?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The faulty assumption is that in strict mode *all* global variables are disallowed. Actually only *undefined* global variables throw an error. (In fact you basically couldn't do anything at all if you couldn't use *any* global variables. There has to be at least something in the global scope.)

For example:

```
"use strict";

var a = "foo";
var b;

(function() {
    a = "bar";  // this is ok, initialized earlier
    b = "baz";  // this is also ok, defined earlier
    c = "qux";  // this is not, creating an implicit global
})();
```

Using variables `a` or `b` is not a problem, but `c` will throw an error. There should be no problems using the `eventApp` variable in your example.

Comment: Tnx, if var a was not initialized  with "foo" then its also an error right?

Comment: As long as it's defined it's ok, so `var a;` is enough.

Comment: I mean using only var a; and not initilazing anymore anywhere in that file

Comment: I am confused, but you said uninitialized global variables throw an error :)

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusing wording. Defining the variable is enough.

Comment: ok so "use strict" "only" throws an error when such thing happens, but it does actually NOT change/modify scope of any variable I define, correct?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to reference  `eventsApp` because angular will hold a reference to the object by the name 'eventsApp' that you are using to define the module.

So, in all other files you can just use:

```
angular.module('eventsApp');
```

To get access to the module.

Comment: srry thi si abit confusing, so you mean eventsApp is not global?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't need to reference `eventsApp` in other files.  In fact, you don't even need to set that variable.  Angular is happy if you define a module like this: `angular.module('eventsApp', []);` and then register a service against a module (in another file) like this: `angular.module('eventsApp').factory('service');`

Comment: I see your point, but my question beyond angular, var eventsApp is global or not? and I understand it is global/window

Comment: I will, tnx for useless 2 cents and suggestion